# Change WooCommerce products menu title in WordPress admin dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, dashboard

We have tried to change the products page at the back end title menu but we couldn't using the snippet below in the screenshot:

[image]

We need to change both the menu title "**Products**" to " **New Title** " & Sumbmenu **"All Products**" to " **All Submenu** "

```php
add_filter( 'gettext', 'custom_translate_woocommerce_strings', 999, 3 );

function custom_translate_woocommerce_strings( $translated, $text, $domain ) {

    $translated = str_ireplace( 'Product', 'New Title', $translated );

    return $translated;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **first part** of the code is to **debug**, this will show you the **menu in detail** on the dashboard. (you can remove this afterwards)

The 2nd part in **this example adds the changes**

[image]

> It is therefore a matter of adjusting based on the detail

```php
// DEBUG: This displays the complete wordpress admin menu on your dashboard for admin only.
function debug_admin_menus() {
    global $menu, $submenu, $pagenow;
    if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
        if( $pagenow == 'index.php' ) {  // print on dashboard
            echo '<pre>', print_r( $menu, 1 ), '</pre>'; // top level menus
            echo '<pre>', print_r( $submenu, 1 ), '</pre>'; // submenus
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'debug_admin_menus' );

// Change label
function custom_change_admin_label() {
    global $menu, $submenu;

    $menu[26][0] = 'New Title';
    $submenu['edit.php?post_type=product'][5][0] = 'All Submenu';
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_change_admin_label' );
```

Comment: Worked great, thank you sir .. can we have your contact info for freelancing work ?

Comment: @MagedMohamed An advice: For free lance contacts, you can choose some people [from the top user list for WooCommerce Tagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/woocommerce/topusers), going through their profiles to get their contact information.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec we just though that top guys are expensive, but how can we contact you sir ?, email ?